# UIScrollView, UIButton vs. UIControl, and touch events

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uibutton, ios6, uicontrol

I have a `UIScrollView` which contains a `UIButton` and a [gradient button](https://github.com/nverinaud/NVUIGradientButton), which is a `UIControl` subclass. The gradient-button draws differently according to whether the user has tapped on it (indicating highlight).

The button behaves regularly inside the scroll-view, while the gradient-button does not: whenever I tap the button, it immediately redraws to indicate it has been highlighted. The gradient-button, however, does not respond immediately. Only if I hold the tap for half a second or so, does it redraw.

It should be noted that outside of a scroll-view, the gradient-button behaves as expected.

It seems to be related to the fact that a `UIScrollView` waits some time before forwarding the events, to decide if it should scroll instead.

My question is - what does `UIButton` do differently? how can I mimic this behavior in the gradient-button? Or maybe is it special treatment on the side of `UIScrollView`?

**EDIT:** The problem appears to be drawing-related. The touch events get called properly, but instead of two calls to `drawRect:` I only get one. Forcing the runloop to process events, as well as calling `[CATransacation flush]`, causes two calls to `drawRect:` to be made, but there's no visible change.